# What is the domain and range of this multivariable function?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

What is the domain and range of the following multivariable function?

$g(x,y,z) = {1\over \sqrt{(4 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)}}$

g is real valued.

So far I have that the domain is the set of a vectors $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 4$, and the range is $[1/2, \infty)$ .

Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Oliver please see my edit

Comment: Does g have to be real-valued?

Comment: yes sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: Yes you are +1. Check [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427elmpjhn0l81)...